# How to map JSON data graphically on a Leaflet map?

Tags: json, reactjs, api, leaflet, react-leaflet

I want to use the Citybik.es API (http://api.citybik.es/) to show data on a Leaflet map.

**How do implement this data on the map from JSON?** I am already fetching information from the API inside a `componentDidMount()`, but I don't have a clue about putting this data into a map.

The response looks something like this:

```
{
  "networks": [
{
  "company": [
    "Bike U Sp. z o.o."
  ], 
  "href": "/v2/networks/bbbike", 
  "id": "bbbike", 
  "location": {
    "city": "Bielsko-Bia\u0142a", 
    "country": "PL", 
    "latitude": 49.8225, 
    "longitude": 19.044444
  }, 
  "name": "BBBike"
}, 
{
  "company": [
    "PBSC", 
    "Alta Bicycle Share, Inc"
  ], 
  "href": "/v2/networks/melbourne-bike-share", 
  "id": "melbourne-bike-share", 
  "location": {
    "city": "Melbourne", 
    "country": "AU", 
    "latitude": -37.814107, 
    "longitude": 144.96328
  }, 
  "name": "Melbourne Bike Share"
}
}
```

Thanks for the help!

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import L from 'leaflet';
import { Map, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet';

// code for map marker icon
var myIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'data:image/png;base64,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',
    iconSize: [25, 41],
    iconAnchor: [12.5, 41],
    popupAnchor: [0, -41]
});

class App extends Component {
    state = {
        location: {
            lat: 51.505,
            lng: -0.09,
        },
        haveUsersLocation: false,
        zoom: 2,
        networks: null
    }

    //lifecycle method to get the user's current position(if they so desire).
    componentDidMount() {

        fetch('https://api.citybik.es/v2/networks')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(response => {
            console.log("response", response);
            console.log(response.networks)
            const networkData = response.networks
            const networkList = networkData.map((data) => {
                console.log(data);
            })
    })


        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
            this.setState({
               location: {
                   lat: position.coords.latitude,
                   lng: position.coords.longitude
               },
               haveUsersLocation: true,
               zoom: 13
            });
        }, () => {
            console.log('Uops! The user didnt give its location!');
            fetch('https://ipapi.co/json')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(location => {
                this.setState({
                    location: {
                        lat: location.latitude,
                        lng: location.longitude
                    },
                    haveUsersLocation: true,
                    zoom: 13
                 });
            })
        });
    }


    render() {
        const position = [this.state.location.lat, this.state.location.lng]
        return (
            <Map className="map" center={position} zoom={this.state.zoom}>
                <TileLayer
                    attribution="&amp;copy <a href=&quot;http://osm.org/copyright&quot;>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors"
                    url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                />
                {
                    this.state.haveUsersLocation ? 
                    <Marker
                        position={position}
                        icon={myIcon}>
                    <Popup>
                        A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
                    </Popup>
                </Marker> : ''
                }
            </Map>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

#root {
    height: 100%;
}

.map {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">

    <title>Leaflet map</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to render multiple `Marker` element. Currently, you are rendering one `Marker` if you have the current users location. In similar fashion, we will iterate through the other co-ordinates and render them.

In your `componentDidMount`, save the response you receive to a state

```
fetch('https://api.citybik.es/v2/networks')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(response => {
        console.log("response", response);
        console.log(response.networks)
        const networkData = response.networks
        const networkList = networkData.map((data) => {
            this.setState({ bikeData: data });
        })
})
```

Then inside your `render` method, iterate over the `bikeData` and render the `Markers`.

```
<Map className="map" center={position} zoom={this.state.zoom}>
            <TileLayer
                attribution="&amp;copy <a href=&quot;http://osm.org/copyright&quot;>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors"
                url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            />
            {
                this.state.haveUsersLocation ? 
                <Marker
                    position={position}
                    icon={myIcon}>
                <Popup>
                    A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
                </Popup>
            </Marker> : ''
            }

            {
              this.state.bikeData &&
              this.state.bikeData.networks.map((idx, data) => (
               <Marker key={data.id} position={[data.location.latitude, data.location.longitude]}> <Popup> Name: {data.name} </Popup> </Marker>))
            } 

        </Map>
```

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: this.state.bikeData.map is not a function`
@Panther

Comment: @RCohen, one should not directly copy paste the answer and try it.. at stack overflow, we just give pointers and not the exact solution. Try to read the error and see what goes wrong and fix them. The problem was that i was trying to `map` on a wrong property. I hope the `this.state.bikeData.networks` is an array and would iterate one. Please use `stackoverflow` to learn and not expect someone to give an exact solution. Check out the updated answer.

Comment: I just mentioned that your code was not working properly. I already had something coded before your answer appeared. We, as developers, are here to share knowledge and help each other. There is nothing wrong on that. @Panther

Answer (score 1):

You'd better reformat the output JSON to GeoJSON, then it would be quite simple to draw object on the map using Leaflet and Mapbox.

Example:

https://gist.github.com/arfeo/3580f3796a31ca95b7cf30b99bfd6be5

```
    const openJsonFile = (file) => {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            const _ = new XMLHttpRequest();
            _.overrideMimeType("application/json");
            _.open("GET", file, true);
            _.onload = function() {
                if(this.readyState == 4) {
                    if(this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300) {
                        resolve(_.responseText);
                    } else {
                        reject(_.statusText);
                    }
                }
            };
            _.onerror = function () {
                reject(_.statusText);
            };
            _.send();
        });
    };

    // Create a map
    const map = L.map('map').setView([55.92, 37.83], 12);

    // Add Mapbox tiles to map
    L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiYXJmZW8iLCJhIjoiY2pjeGw5bG5nMTF5ZjMzczZoZWVzbWdyNSJ9.Yh3u2uEHErWpTvAg3Ak_qw', {
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
        maxZoom: 20,
        id: 'mapbox.streets',
        accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoiYXJmZW8iLCJhIjoiY2pjeGw5bG5nMTF5ZjMzczZoZWVzbWdyNSJ9.Yh3u2uEHErWpTvAg3Ak_qw'
    }).addTo(map);

    // Open and parse heojson file
    openJsonFile("output.geojson")
        .then(function(json) {
            const data = JSON.parse(json);

            // Draw GeoJSON features on map
            for(const feature of data.features) {
                const x = L.geoJSON(feature).addTo(map);

                // If a feature is Point, add a popup (if applicable)
                if(feature.geometry.type === "Point")
                    x.bindPopup((name = feature.properties.name) ? name : null);
            }
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.error("Error:", error);
        });
```