# Draw country border on leaflet map using JSON coordinates

Tags: javascript, json, leaflet, polygon, openstreetmap

I have a leaflet map, and I have a set of country borders in a long JSON file. I am trying to use the JSON coordinates to draw a solid green border along the border of a country displayed in the map object.

I do not want to draw a fully covered layer over the country either.

I have built a JS function that makes an Ajax call to request JSON border coordinates for a specific country.

When the JSON data is received, I apply and bound it to the map object.

```
function applyCountryBorder(countryname) {
    var addresssObj = null;

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?country=' + countryname.trim() + '&polygon_geojson=1&format=json',
        async: true,
        cache: true,
        success: function(responseData) {
             var polyline = L.polyline(responseData[0].geojson.coordinates, {
                color: 'green',
                weight: 14,
                opacity: 1    
            }).addTo(map);
            map.invalidateSize();
        },
        error: function(responseData) {
            addresssObj =  responseData;}
    });
}
```

I expect the border of the specified country to have a bright, solid, thick, green line. But actually, the map and country borders remain unchanged and remain default.

What am I doing wrong? How can I achieve the desired goal?

Comment: Maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52539033/how-to-map-json-data-graphically-on-a-leaflet-map) can help out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely border (MultiPolygon shape) is getting rendered but just not on the place you expect it to. In GeoJSON format coordinates are represented in `lng,lat` order while `L.polyline` expects the coordinates in format `lat,lng`, in another words GeoJSON coordinates (`lng,lat`) needs to swapped  to `lat,lng`.

[`L.GeoJSON.coordsToLatLng()` function](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#geojson-coordstolatlng) could be utilized for that matter, for example

```
const latLngs = L.GeoJSON.coordsToLatLngs(data[0].geojson.coordinates,2); 
L.polyline(latLngs, {
    color: "green",
    weight: 14,
    opacity: 1
}).addTo(map);
```

---

Since a provided service returns GeoJSON, another option would be to utilize [`L.geoJSON`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#geojson) to render a border like this:

```js
const layer = L.tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
  maxZoom: 19,
  attribution:
    '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
});

const map = L.map("map", {
  layers: [layer]
}).setView([52.8203934, -4.5700609], 6);
applyCountryBorder(map, "United Kingdom");

function applyCountryBorder(map, countryname) {
  jQuery
    .ajax({
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      url:
        "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?country=" +
        countryname.trim() +
        "&polygon_geojson=1&format=json"
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      /*const latLngs = L.GeoJSON.coordsToLatLngs(data[0].geojson.coordinates,2) 
      L.polyline(latLngs, {
        color: "green",
        weight: 14,
        opacity: 1
      }).addTo(map);*/

      L.geoJSON(data[0].geojson, {
        color: "green",
        weight: 14,
        opacity: 1,
        fillOpacity: 0.0 
      }).addTo(map);
    });
}
```

```css
#map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 480px;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.css"
/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: How do I get just the border and no color fill inside? Apparently this draws the border as well as fills layer with a color too. Is it possible to have transparent fill , but solid border only?

Comment: @MorganJanjuaCrane, i guess you are after  `fillOpacity: 0.0`  property, the example has been updated